How to handle touchpad force click in macos/chrome?
In youtube when you force click on a video while playing in a chrome browser, the video would be played at 2x.
Packages like Pressure.js cannot detect force click in chrome browser. How does youtube handle it?

YouTube could just be using a timer on the mousedown event. The timer just sees for how long you've held down on your mouse to validate if you're force clicking/holding.
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown',function() { 
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Holding!");
  }, 500);
});


ahhh, silly me.

I've just tested the behaviour on a 2023 Macbook Air, and here's a few notes:
Firefox, Chrome, and Safari all behave the same for me in Youtube.

Click-and-hold with trackpad fast-forwards a YT video.
Click-and-hold with a regular mouse does the same thing.
Force-hold does the same behaviour as regular-hold in all instances.

I'm pretty sure Monke is right here, Youtube just doesn't seem to use the force touch features at all.
